# Expect vs. Foresee

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

Just read the sentence "This is not what I expect but what I foresee." 
Does this make sense to anyone here?
Granted there are differences in meaning between 'expect' and 'foresee' but to me they are not very drastic and the sentence is not logically coherent; if you foresee something shouldn't you also expect it?

Comment: Unless you are a medium with self-trust issues, I don't think the sentence makes much sense, indeed. It sounds a bit like the speaker meant something like "It's not what I _hope for_, but it is what I expect".

Comment: That makes absolute sense. First: synonyms need not be interchangeable. *Expect* and *foresee* have distinct meanings/ connotations, esp., in contexts such as this. HTH. Let us know if you need a full-fledged answer.

Comment: I suppose the writer could mean that he can imagine a particular scenario as one of infinite possibilities while also holding that the likelihood of its occurrence is low. Though I still feel that this is an inelegant way of conveying that, if that is indeed what he means.

Comment: Perhaps the writer means "I don't just expect this - I foresee it".  It's like someone saying "I don't like you.  I love you."  Still, an awkward sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *expect* often implies a sense of logical thought. You expect 2 to come after 1, or A to come before B. These notions are what experience or reasonable supposition leads you to believe.

To *foresee* can also imply the same knowledge based on what you are aware of, but it also carries an element of the mystical, and so can be held apart from logical or reasonable cause-effect situations.

I think it is a bit too thin a difference to really draw a line on, but the nuance is there nonetheless.

Comment: I was inclined to agree with @oerkelens (see comment on main question), but this answer does open up at least a conceivable line of interpretation of the sentence:  The speaker could mean that the foreseen event is not logical, but nevertheless has been "fated" to happen.  (I do still agree with everyone who is not favorably impressed by the quality of the sentence.)

Answer (score 2):

Expect can imply to wish for something or to hope for something.

For instance, are you familiar with the phrase "what I expect or hope for" (512K hits on google)?

According to [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expect?s=t)  "Expect implies confidently believing, usually for good reasons, that an event will occur".  It lists "hope" and "anticipate" as synonyms.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expect) gives one definition of *expect* as "to consider (something) to be reasonable, required, or necessary".  It also lists "hope" and "anticipate" as synonyms.

Or as Jane Austin put it:

> “...to wish was to hope, and to hope was to expect” [Sense and
>   Sensibility](http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/jausten/bl-jausten-sen-4.htm)

For a longer analysis, here's a paper that reflects some effort in analysis on the topic - this from the abstract, and, while there's always debate, the paper notes one researcher, Dixon, classifies *expect* with *hope* as "belonging to the WANTING type":

> According to Dixon (2005: 409), the verbs hope and expect belong to
>   the WANTING type. Quirk et al. (1985: 1114), on the other hand,
>   classify these comment clauses into three types in which I hope is
>   said to express the speaker’s emotional attitude, and I expect is said
>   to express the speaker’s tentativeness over the truth value of the
>   matrix clause. Historically, hope is a native English word, already
>   used actively in the Old English period, while expect derived from
>   Latin ex(s)pectare (‘await’), and came into English about the middle
>   of the 16th century. Irrespective of their provenance, in present-day
>   English, however, these two verbs behave similarly, with some
>   differences in meaning, taking the to-infinitive and that or zero
>   clauses. But at the same time, they differ in some functions. While
>   hope is often used in the form of I hope (that), expect is more often
>   used in the form of ‘expect to do something’. I hope is also more
>   frequent in parenthetical use than I expect. [Rivalry between expect and hope with particular reference to their constructional developments](http://www.helsinki.fi/varieng/series/volumes/10/akimoto/)

*Foresee* doesn't imply that the result is hoped for.

The logical conclusion is that the speaker is emphasizing that this is not a result that is hoped for, but a result that is believed will happen nonetheless.

I'm not sure that everyone uses this much nuance between *expect* and *foresee* but I don't think it's necessarily incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overlook the fact that *expect* has other definitions. In this case ([Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expect)):

> to consider (something) to be reasonable, required, or necessary

For example:

> I expect the children to behave like angels when we enter the museum.

The retort might be:

> I do too, but I foresee problems with that one over there.

Answer (score 0):

I definitely don't think it's a virtuous use of English. However, there are subtle differences in meaning between the words *forsee* and *expect*.

*Foresee* conveys more certainty regarding the outcome, because of its etymological origin which is derived from the meaning *to see ahead*.<sup>1</sup>

*Expect* is actually implying slight uncertainty. Its meaning originates from Latin *expectare/exspectare* meaning "await, look out for; desire, hope, long for, anticipate; look for with anticipation".<sup>2</sup>

..

With that preface in mind, the sentence could mean "I don't just anticipate this. I am certain of it."

<sup>1</sup>[Source (etymonline.com)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=foresee)

<sup>2</sup>[Source (etymonline.com)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=expect)

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain?